# how to get reproducible splits using LassoLarsCV in sklearn?

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, random-seed, reproducible-research

If I fit a `LassoCV` using `sklearn`, I can do

```
    model_LassoCV = LassoCV(cv=3,random_state=2018).fit(X, y)
```

and get reproducible splits for the cross-validation.
However, if I do

```
    model_LassoCV = LassoLarsCV(cv=3,random_state=2018).fit(X, y)
```

according to the documentation, `LassoLarsCV` does not have a `random_state`.
So how to get reproducible results with `LassoLarsCV` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object to be used as a cross-validation generator can be passed as `cv` param. So you can pass your own CV iterator to control the train test generation.

Something like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=2018)
model_LassoCV = LassoLarsCV(cv=kfold)
model_LassoCV.fit(X, y)
```

Now you need to make sure that randomness is not present anywhere else in the algorithm and if it does not, then this will be duplicateable code.

Comment: then If I pass a CV iterator also to LassoCV, the random_state will be ignored there?

Comment: Yes, if the `random_state` is not being used for any other thing in the algorithm. Which in my opinion it does not.

Comment: thanks this is a good answer. I will wait to approve to see if anybody knows if random_state  is also used somewhere else

Comment: @ErroriSalvo You can verify that yourself by running the above code multiple times. If you get exact same output then its reproducible.

Comment: Or take a look at the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L1246) to make really sure.

Comment: @kazemakase The way scikit works, extending base classes, it will be hard to go through source like this.

Comment: @VivekKumar of course one has to dig through all bases and dependencies - I never said it would be easy ;) However, it's the only way to be *absolutely* sure.. if going through that is worth the effort is for anyone to decide themselves.